# menu file did not played when user play "*",Asterisk-11.5.1 Confbridge

Tags: c, centos, sip, asterisk, conference

Dialout user Pickuped/Answer call and merge into Confbridge but Admin getting "Ringtone" Asterisk-11.5.1 Confbridge . ?

**Expected :** admin user (A 7002) ,of current Conference Dailout and Invite user (B 7001)  to join Confernece. B Picked call and joined Confbridge.
A and B should Communincate with each other and press "*" to listen conf Menu file.

**Originale:** B can listen menu by Press "*"; 
A can not Talk to B .
A press * ,but MenuFile did not  played . 
A only getting "Ringingtone".
Why, any help ?

```
C**onference Bridge Name           Users  Marked Locked?
================================ ====== ====== ========
1010101                               2      1 unlocked**

*CLI> confbridge list 1010101 
Channel                       User Profile     Bridge Profile   Menu             CallerID
============================= ================ ================ ================ ================
SIP/7002-00000009                              default_bridge   conf-admin-sub-dialout7002             
SIP/7001-0000000a             default_user     default_bridge   conf-admin-sub-dialout7001


  *CLI> sip show channels 
Peer             User/ANR         Call ID          Format           Hold     Last Message    Expiry     Peer      
XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX   7001             1deffeb72b0f045  (ulaw)           No       Tx: ACK                    7001      
XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX   7002             fd2d41c9-e39354  (ulaw)           No       Tx: ACK                    7002      

==========================================================================
  *CLI> sip show channel 65a218b00e4e389

  * SIP Call
  Curr. trans. direction:  Outgoing
  Call-ID:                65a218b00e4e389f56c1327c684e8513@XYZ.XYZ.XYZ.XYZ:5060
  Owner channel ID:       SIP/7001-0000000c
  Our Codec Capability:   (ulaw|alaw)
  Non-Codec Capability (DTMF):   1
  Their Codec Capability:   (ulaw)
  Joint Codec Capability:   (ulaw)
  Format:                 (ulaw)
  T.38 support            No
  Video support           No
  MaxCallBR:              384 kbps
  Theoretical Address:    XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX:5060
  Received Address:       XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX:5060
  SIP Transfer mode:      open
  Force rport:            Yes
  Audio IP:               XYZ.XYZ.XYZ.XYZ (local)
  Our Tag:                as420f4f04
  Their Tag:              864d22e793aa05b8i0
  SIP User agent:         
  Username:               7001
  Peername:               7001
  Original uri:           sip:7001@XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX:5060
  Caller-ID:              91xxxxxxxxxxxx
  Need Destroy:           No
  Last Message:           Tx: ACK
  Promiscuous Redir:      No
  Route:                  <sip:7001@XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX:5060>
  DTMF Mode:              rfc2833
  SIP Options:            (none)
  Session-Timer:          Inactive

===========================================================================
*CLI> sip show channel fd2d41c9-e39354

  * SIP Call
  Curr. trans. direction:  Outgoing
  Call-ID:                fd2d41c9-e3935429@XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX
  Owner channel ID:       SIP/7002-00000009
  Our Codec Capability:   (ulaw|alaw)
  Non-Codec Capability (DTMF):   1
  Their Codec Capability:   (ulaw)
  Joint Codec Capability:   (ulaw)
  Format:                 (ulaw)
  T.38 support            No
  Video support           No
  MaxCallBR:              384 kbps
  Theoretical Address:    XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX:5061
  Received Address:       XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX:5061
  SIP Transfer mode:      open
  Force rport:            Yes
  Audio IP:               XYZ.XYZ.XYZ.XYZ (local)
  Our Tag:                as165d44ab
  Their Tag:              316d654987e586a9o1
  SIP User agent:         Linksys/PAP2T-3.1.15(LS)
  Username:               7002
  Peername:               7002
  Original uri:           sip:7002@XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX:5061
  Caller-ID:              7002
  Need Destroy:           No
  Last Message:           Tx: ACK
  Promiscuous Redir:      No
  Route:                  <sip:7002@XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX:5061>
  DTMF Mode:              rfc2833
  SIP Options:            
  Session-Timer:          Inactive
============================================================

*CLI> sip show channelstats 
Peer             Call ID      Duration Recv: Pack  Lost       (     %) Jitter Send: Pack  Lost       (     %) Jitter
XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX   5e81a94e-44  00:03:51 0000010612  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000 0000009484  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0006
XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX   65a218b00e4  00:02:17 0000006816  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000 0000006632  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0006

======================================================

CLI> sip show channels
Peer             User/ANR         Call ID          Format           Hold     Last Message    Expiry     Peer      
XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX   7002             5e81a94e-449935  (ulaw)           No       Tx: ACK                    7002      
XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX   7001             65a218b00e4e389  (ulaw)           No       Tx: ACK                    7001      

========================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it ,By Using AMI and Originate app .now Works as expected.